# Understanding MySql Auto_Increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a column in a table that is auto incremented. Let's call it `employee_id`.

Let the initial value be 1 and let it be incremented by 1 for each insertion.
After inserting 10 rows, the auto incremented value becomes 10 (`employee_id` is 10).

Now if I manually insert 11th row with an employee Id as 15 , and then allow MySql's `AUTO_INCREMENT` to take over, will the next auto incremented value be 11 or 16 ?

Comment: Offtopic: 1. Always use consistent case in variable (column/table) name, 2. never use space in column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be 16, bcs MySQL will update the value of AUTO_INCREMENT counter after each insert/update operation. This is for both most popular table engines, MyISAM and InnoDB:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: I'm not agree, please, read this first: After the auto-increment counter has been initialized, if a you do not explicitly specify a value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column, InnoDB increments the counter and assigns the new value to the column. If you insert a row that explicitly specifies the column value, and the value is bigger than the current counter value, the counter is set to the specified column value.

Comment: yes, this is from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on localhost and after inserting 15th row manually (`employee_id=10, name=John`), it is going on by getting `max auto_increment id`.

Storage Engine of table is: MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

Next Auto_increament value will be 16. As Auto_increament will be updated after every insert/delete operation.